# Правильно ли будет опустить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Мы же не знаем() когда, а главное() почему девушка сделала тот звонок.**

Хочется оставить запятую только перед "а".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что ваше предложение должно выглядеть так:
**Мы же не знаем, когда, а главное, почему девушка сделала тот звонок.**

Запятая в любом случае необходима перед  союзом *когда*, чтобы выделить последующее придаточное предложение. *Главное* - здесь выполняет функцию вводного слова.

> Запятая после союза ставится, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры. Если же изъятие вводного слова невозможно (т. е. союз включается во вводную конструкцию, образуя с ней единое сочетание), то запятая после союза не ставится (обычно это бывает при союзе а).

Здесь вводное слово мы опустить не можем, значит, *а главное* - это единое вводное сочетание, которое необходимо выделить запятыми.

В *Нацкорпусе* встретил такое предложение:

> До сих пор остается много неясного, а главное ― почему было принято фатальное решение о вводе войск в Афганистан?

У вас, как мне кажется, также можно поставить тире после *а главное*, как бы делая акцент на главном вопросе:
**Мы же не знаем, когда, а главное — почему девушка сделала тот звонок.**

Answer (score 2):

Здесь возможны 2 варианта, потому что синтаксическая конструкция неоднозначна.

Одни могут увидеть сложноподчинённое предложение с однородными обстоятельствами когда и почему:

*Мы же не знаем, когда, а главное - почему девушка сделала тот звонок.* Возможна и запятая после вводного.

Другие увидят два сложноподчинённых, второе - с неполным главным:

*Мы же не знаем когда,   а главное( не знаем)- почему девушка сделала тот звонок.*

Тогда в первом предложении придаточное выражено только  союзным словом и перед ним нет запятой (оно синонимично простому), пауза перед А очень большая. Вы эту паузу сделали, разделили конструкцию на две части, потому и не захотелось ставить запятую. Это возможно, но как авторская конструкция.

Comment: "Мы же не знаем когда". В отрыве от последующего это звучит бессмыссленно. На мой взгляд, этот вариант не выдерживает конкуренции с другим, простым и логичным: *Мы же не знаем, когда и почему девушка сделала тот звонок" + вводная конструкция "а главное".

Answer (score 0):

**Мы же не знаем когдА, а главное,  почемУ // девушка сделала тот звонок.**

Знаки препинания расставлены в соответствии с **интонационным принципом**.

Но это же несерьезно, скажете вы. У нас основным принципом является грамматический, а это значит, что перед "когда" надо поставить запятую и  вводное слово "а главное" следует обособить. Ну тире можно поставить вместо одно запятой (после "главное" часто встречается тире). Какие проблемы?

Интонация? Так интонационный принцип не всегда действует, в частности в сложных предложениях вводные конструкции могут и не выделяться паузами.

**Это простое (на школьном уровне) решение, которое, скорее всего, всех устраивает.**

Но только вот предложение это не такое простое, чтобы такой  разбор был очевиден. **Дело в том, что   интонация здесь не только не соответствует грамматическому принципу — она ему противоречит.** Перед  союзным словом "когда" пауза явно отсутствует, а на союзное слово падает ударение. И кроме того, здесь два союзных слова, связанные однородными отношениями.  **Так что грамматика  совсем не стандартная.**

Сравним исходный вариант со следующим предложением:

Мы же не знаем ни кОгда, ни почемУ // девушка сделала тот звонОк.

Интонация похожа, ударение также падает на союзные слова, запятая перед "когда" по правилам (перед союзом НИ...НИ) не ставится. Это интонация простого предложения, осложненного однородными членами в первой его части.

Вот такой вариант. Чтобы сказать, что он неверен, надо найти в правилах нечто похожее, **а именно однородные союзные слова, разделенные паузой и запятой**.

Comment: Не поняла, почему в предложении Мы же не знаем когда и почему девушка сделала тот звонок  нет знаков, "когда и почему" не выделяются запятыми. Это что, не СПП? Мы не знаем - главное, (чего?)когда и почему девушка сделала тот звонок - придаточное изъяснительное. Было бы без знаков:  Мы же не знаем когда и почему.

Comment: Можете прокомментировать, почему вы в своем примере не ставите запятую перед "когда"? Не могу придумать причину, чтобы ее убрать из предложения.